# Issues with Event Aggregator using Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, mef, system.reactive, eventaggregator

To link up my [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) application, I'm using the event aggregator [found here](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/). Its been perfect for distributing data into modules that actually need it.

I'm getting more into using the reactive extensions and I've been trying to do the following:

```
eventSubscription = MainApp.Events.GetEvent<UDPMessageIn>()
                                  .BufferWithTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                                  .Subscribe(x => 
                                       { 
                                           // do something here...
                                       });
```

However, the event aggregator appears to hang in the Publish method on:

```
((ISubject<TEvent>)subject).OnNext(sampleEvent);
```

I'm guessing that there's something about the design of either system.reactive or the aggregator that I don't fully understand. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Reactive Extensions, but I'll watch this question to learn more. Btw, what is MEF?

Comment: Managed Extensibility Framework. http://mef.codeplex.com/. Its built into .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a threading issue that was unrelated to Rx or the event aggregator.

Changing one of my UI Invokes to BeginInvoke stopped it from hanging and this got me looking at the right bits of code...

Answer (score 1):

What threads are both the producer and consumer running on? Are they separate?

Try:

```
.BufferWithTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.TaskPool);
```